# Eclipse IDE: Failed to initialize monitor thread error after installing Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed the android SDK plugin for Eclipse and whenever I start my IDE (eclipse) I get the error alert `"failed to initialize monitor thread. Unable to establish loopback connection"`. Then in the console, It goes onto repeated connection attempts that look like this `[2011-09-04 16:21:53 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 37`  Over and over (there were 36 of these messages in the console, that is the 37th).

My IDE is eclipse classic (helios). I've tried it with the new version 3.7 (indigo) but the same error occurs.

I've been trying to work this out. It has been almost 3 weeks I've done all the googling research etc but I've not been able to find an answer that resolved this...

Comment: Somebody had similar problem, try doing what that person said. link:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432078/problem-running-android-hello-world-eclipse-3-5-win-7

Comment: I read that in my research, however in my case it comes up at the start of the IDE not when i run the emulator. The emulator isn't even started yet.

Comment: Have you tried smth like here? http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/39f582e58ec61edb#

Comment: I had the same problem. I disconnected my computer from the internet and the problem solved!!! Now Im sure its related to one of my other softwares (in my case that was proxifier) . I think it might be related to converting IPv4 to IPv6 addresses or something.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the reason was a wrong Java JDK. If you have installed the Java JDK 7, uninstall it at first and reinstall the JDK 6 -> [download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

I don't know if it works if you just download the JDK 6 and set the JAVA_HOME path to it.
I uninstalled the JDK 7, because I didn't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure localhost is pointing to 127.0.0.1
2. Disable your firewall

Although not Android, this thread also talks about that issue:

http://www.java.net/node/693759

Comment: it didn't work. I turned off firewall and made localhost point to that point by changing the file in system32 but had no effect

Answer (score 0):

Solution (workaround) : turn off Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface.

This probably converts IP4 to IPv6 addresses or something, resulting in an IPv6 address for your localhost (strange though, that a PING still results in IP4). Anyway, turning it off (Device manager > View > Show hidden devices > right click on Teredo > disable) solves the problem!

I found that my Win7 install re-enables my Teredo device after each boot. Even when I deinstall. So I made a batchfile (run as Administrator) which issues the following commands : >netsh interface teredo set state disabled >"D:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I use Avast Internet Security. I tried allowing eclipse.exe through the firewall, but it still gave me the error.

I simply turned off the Avast firewall, while keeping the Windows firewall on, and it worked. I had no errors at all and it's all smooth sailing.

This may not work for everyone, but after following pretty much every solution thread (none of which worked) I just ended the 3rd party firewall, and boom. Thar' she blows!

I know the question is over 2 years old, but I recently ran into this issue and just wanted to share my experience.