# Eclipse DDMS error: "Failed to initialize Monitor Thread" After installing ADT Plugin?

Tags: sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse IDE: Failed to initialize monitor thread error after installing Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300211/eclipse-ide-failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-error-after-installing-android)

I just installed the ADT Plugin for eclipse but I keep getting the error alert on start of eclipse: `Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection` after I click `OK` It goes onto repeated connection attempts that look like this

`[2011-09-20 13:19:58 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 321`

There are 320 other logs like this in my eclipse console and it increases like every second or so. I've been trouble shooting this for almost a week now I can't seem to figure out what to do. I've uninstalled and re-installed the sdk, un-installed and re-installed eclipse but this error still comes up. Does anyone have any Idea what to do?

My development platform in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
disabling firewall didn't help.
then I've killed my antivirus with with firewall.
and then it began to work.